# Pandas set subset of column to the same dict value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

If I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'B': [4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df['C'] = None

   A  B     C
0  1  4  None
1  1  5  None
2  1  6  None
3  2  7  None
4  2  8  None
5  2  9  None
```

How can I set a subset of `C` to the same dictionary value? For example, set `C` for all rows where `A==1` to `{'example': 5}`?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
df.loc[df['A']==1, 'C'] = {'example': 5}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where` in this case:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']==1, {'example': 5}, df['C'])
```

Output:

```
   A  B               C
0  1  4  {'example': 5}
1  1  5  {'example': 5}
2  1  6  {'example': 5}
3  2  7             NaN
4  2  8             NaN
5  2  9             NaN
```

---

**Update** since `{'example': 5}` is an iterable object, Pandas will try to unfold it when you assign it to a column, hence the length mismatch error if you do directly. To assign the whole column with that dictionary, you need to wrap it in another iterable with the same length as `df`:

```
df['C'] = [{'example':5} for _ in df.index]
```

Output:

```
   A  B               C
0  1  4  {'example': 5}
1  1  5  {'example': 5}
2  1  6  {'example': 5}
3  2  7  {'example': 5}
4  2  8  {'example': 5}
5  2  9  {'example': 5}
```

That said, unless it is really necessary, complex object within Pandas dataframe should be avoided when possible.

---

**Update 2**: per BEN's comment, and also reflected in **Update**

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']==1, {'example': 5}, df['C'])
```

might copy the same object `{'example':5}` to all the valid rows, which may not be the expected behavior. So for that some thing like:

```
df['C'] = [{'example':5} if a==1 else c for a,c in zip(df['A'], df['C'])]
```

would create **different copies** of `{'example':5'}` to the respective rows.

Comment: Thanks! I think you were first but I can't actually quite tell :)

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, how can I set the entire column of C to that dict value? Will accept this answer once it allows

Comment: 2nd 1 is more safe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A']==1, {'example': 5}, df['C'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A  B               C
0  1  4  {'example': 5}
1  1  5  {'example': 5}
2  1  6  {'example': 5}
3  2  7            None
4  2  8            None
5  2  9            None
```

Comment: It is not safe ~